# How to solve Vtiger error : "Duplicate Profile Exists" while changing profile privileges

Tags: crm, vtiger

While updating field level privileges for profile in Vtiger CRM configuration, I get an error message : Duplicate Profile Exists

[image: Error screenshot attached]

Answer (score 0):

Bymistake clicking on the duplicate button, It looks like view but it duplicates the error. The right way to go for edit is click on 3 dots and there is edit button.
UX design flaw.